# Deleted objects in a database SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there any view or system table in SQL Server which returns all the deleted
objects (tables, views etc) in a particular database?

Comment: What is the actual issue you've got that has led to you asking this question?

Answer (score 5):

No.

Once they are deleted they are gone.

The space consumed by them will eventually be overwritten, it might be possible to get some information from analysis of the data files before this happens or the transaction log but there is nothing built in.

Comment: Or possibly restore a backup and examine the schema.

Comment: Does   select * from sys.objects says something on deleted objects!!

Comment: @user1254579 no. Same as `SELECT * FROM anytable` doesn't return deleted rows. There might be stuff about them still on the data pages used by the system base tables behind that view but that would need `dbcc page` and manual decoding of the binary data to find it.

Comment: The answer isn't a simple No.

Comment: @PaulAndrew yes it is. Read the question. `Is there any view or system table in sql server ,which gives all the deleted objects(Tables,Views etc) in a particular database` answer. No there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    [Operation],
    [Transaction Id],
    [Transaction SID],
    [Transaction Name],
    [Begin Time],
    [SPID],
    [Description]
FROM 
    fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE 
    [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
```

Source: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/

Comment: what does it do!? It gives blank when i run it

Comment: @user1254579 returns details about object drop events using the database log file... Like you asked for.

Comment: Are there any pre-requisites for that (SQL version maybe).  I just tried it on a SQL 2008 instance and it returned nothing after I dropped a table.  Database had recovery mode set to FULL.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder did you just change the recovery model to full? If so it doesn't actually operate in full mode until you do the first full backup.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder check out the source link I included. Thanks

Comment: It was already set to full - I'll have a play around - I'm probably doing something daft but this could be useful so thanks.